# AngularUI control for photo album

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Is there an existing control like `ng-grid` (with all its features) that can be used to display a photo album? Or is it possible to tweak `ng-grid` to make it look like a photo album?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind I'm an Angular noob so take it all with a grain of salt.

You could check out row templates on this page:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Think it might do what you want.  Another option might be something like this angular carousel:
http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/

I've been using RoyalSliderJS from CodeCanyon (small licensing fee for usage).  It handles images, video from vimeo/youtube, html content, full screen, touch friendly, and is pretty easy to customize using CSS.  It's $14 per usage, but IMHO totally worth it.  Here's my AngularJS "wrapper" for the royal slider:

```
angular.module("royalSlider", []).directive("royalSlider", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes){
      var rsOptions = {
                  // options go here
                  // as an example, enable keyboard arrows nav
                  keyboardNavEnabled: true,
                  autoScaleSlider:true,
                  fullscreen: {
                    // fullscreen options go here
                    enabled: false,
                    native: true
                  }
              };
      return $(".royalSlider").royalSlider(rsOptions);
    }
  }
});
```

You just use this then give any div the class of royalSlider and it'll be processed by the royal slider script when it's shown.

You can see it in action here (note site is an active work in progress, refining Angular skills as I go):
http://intellect-tech.com/#/portfolio

Comment: shaunshusain, thank you for directive.

But I have small problem: when I use ng-repeat (for example, `<a class="rsImg" href="http://digitalteam.s3.amazonaws.com/zagorod/fd41hfgh1cg1g4g2a3ehc1h1-1-md" ng-repeat="photo in [0,1,2]">image description<img src="http://digitalteam.s3.amazonaws.com/zagorod/fd41hfgh1cg1g4g2a3ehc1h1-1-md" class="rsTmb"></a>`, slider doesn't work (container is empty).

Comment: Hi Eugene Rodionov, sorry but I had actually completely forgotten about doing this.  Looking back on it this was a nice component though so I might get back to this in the next couple of weeks but right now slammed with things to do.